# XgBoost Simulation Relative Importance

Tags: r, machine-learning, simulation, boosting, importance

I am using Xgboost to find the relative contribution of features to the dependent variables. I am running a simulation wherein I'm generating a simulated data-set based on a prespecified mean and variance. There are 6 independent variables `X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, and X6.` The dependent variable `dep` is an average of these 6 variables. Therefore, XGBOOST should output a rel contribution of `1/6` for each variable. However, this is not what I am getting when I am running the code. I have attached the code for your reference. Can anyone tell where am I going wrong?

```
#Creating the data set
set.seed(123456789)
cov_sim1 <- matrix(c(857.7941,0,0,0,0,0,0,15065.39,0,0,0,0,0,0,18.38235,0,0,0,0,0,0,985.8595,0,0,0,0,0,0,35719.32,0,0,0,0,0,0,174.683), nrow = 6, ncol =6)
mean_sim <- c(-2.368421, 3.000000, 1.052632, 18.631579, -33.210526, -5.473684) 
dat <- MASS::mvrnorm(19, mu = mean_sim, Sigma = cov_sim1, empirical = TRUE)
simulated_set <- data.frame(dat)
simulated_set$dep <-(simulated_set$X1 + simulated_set$X2 + simulated_set$X3 + simulated_set$X4 + simulated_set$X5 + simulated_set$X6)/6
```

```
# Setting parameter and tuning
xgb_trcontrol <- caret::trainControl(
  method = "cv", 
  number = 2,
  allowParallel = TRUE, 
  verboseIter = FALSE, 
  returnData = FALSE
)

obj <- 'reg:squarederror'

xgb_grid <- base::expand.grid(
  list(
    nrounds = c(100, 200),
    max_depth = c(2, 4, 6), # maximum depth of a tree
    colsample_bytree = seq(from=0.1, to=1, by=0.1), # subsample ratio of columns when construction each tree
    eta = seq(from=0.1, to=1, by=0.1),    
    gamma = 0, # minimum loss reduction,
    min_child_weight = 1,  # minimum sum of instance weight (hessian) needed ina child
    subsample = 1    # subsample ratio of the training instances
  ))
```

```
#Fitting the model and extracting feature importance

d <- data.matrix(simulated_set[1:6])
set.seed(10302)
xgb_model <- caret::train(
  d, simulated_set$dep,
  trControl = xgb_trcontrol,
  tuneGrid = xgb_grid,
  method = "xgbTree",
  nthread = 10,
  verbose = FALSE,
  metric = "RMSE",
  verbosity = 0
)
bestfit <- xgb_model$bestTune
nrounds_bestfit <- bestfit[1,1]
max_depth_bestfit <- bestfit[1,2]
eta_bestfit <- bestfit[1,3]
colsample_bytree_bestfit <- bestfit[1,4]
min_child_weight_bestfit <- bestfit[1,5]
subsample_bestfit <- bestfit[1,6]
bst <- xgboost(booster = "gbtree", data = d, label = simulated_set$dep, max.depth = max_depth_bestfit, 
           nround = nrounds_bestfit, eta = eta_bestfit,
             min_child_weight <- min_child_weight_bestfit)
importance <- xgb.importance(model = bst)
importance <- importance[order(importance$Feature),]
ac <- as.data.frame(importance)
```

I have tried to standardize the variables as well.  That does not change the output by much? My initial thinking is that it depends on the variance of the dependent variables. But, not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differences in variance are most definitely the reason for the observed differences in importance.

Broadly, you would only expect the result to show ~`.167` for a `lm`'s set of coefficients.  Because of the way `simulated_set[["dep"]]` is defined, the mean value is determined by mulitplying all `X` variables by one-sixth.

```
> sapply(coef(lm(dep ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6, simulated_set)), round, digits=5)
(Intercept)          X1          X2          X3          X4          X5 
    0.00000     0.16667     0.16667     0.16667     0.16667     0.16667 
         X6 
    0.16667
```

Importance statistics usually involve model fit, and `xgboost` is no exception.  This idea is easier to see for simpler metrics though like `lm`-based importance metrics such as [Dominance Analysis](https://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/000313007X188252#.YB1nk-hKi9I)/DA which is explained well in the linked article by Grömping.

Take the same model and run it through a DA (implemented by [domir](https://github.com/jluchman/domir) but equivalent results can be obtained by [dominanceanalysis](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dominanceanalysis/index.html) and [relaimpo](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/relaimpo/index.html)) and you get:

```
> sapply(domir::domin(dep ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6, lm, list(summary, "r.squared"), data=simulated_set)$General_Dominance, round, digits=5)
     X1      X2      X3      X4      X5      X6 
0.01624 0.28521 0.00035 0.01866 0.67623 0.00331 

> sapply(simulated_set[-7], sd)
        X1         X2         X3         X4         X5         X6
 29.288122 122.741150   4.287464  31.398400 188.995556  13.216770
```

Very much dependent on the variances as can be seen.  Whereas this article focuses on random forest, a comparison between linear models and random forest is discussed [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/tast.2009.08199); it provides good description of similarities and differences between the approaches that might help to explain the results.

Comment: Thanks @jiluchman This is really helpful. Are you aware of any methods that give importance matrix robust to the variance structure?

Comment: @RaghavGoyal, I suppose one way to avoid the variances issue is to not use a fit metric - as such.  The -lm- coefficients outlined above are an example of a set of metrics that do not describe model fit but rather predicted values/conditional means. Generalizing that idea to -xgboost-, you might try techniques like SHAP (https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/shap.html) that do something similar-ish (but as you'll see doesn't produce coefficients quite like -lm-).

Comment: Thanks @jluchman.But how do I find the relative importance of features from mean SHAP scores? I mean the mean absolute SHAP values for all features is much greater than 100. Shouldn't they sum to 1 or 100% ?

Comment: This is where things get tricky as it's easier to define what sums to 100% in a fit metric (i.e., components of explaining fit) - but doing so with conditional means/predicted values where some predictors increase, and some decrease, scores is not as well defined.  SHAP is more like -lm-'s coefficients in my view and one could infer that bigger absolute changes to predicted values make a variable more important; those changes are likely to be partly due to variance of the underlying predictor as well however.